# ColdFusion 2018 and DSN - Timed out trying to establish a connection

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, dsn, coldfusion-2018

I'm currently having issues with our ColdFusion 2018 Application Server in production.  If we need to restart the ColdFusion 2018 service or the server reboots after patching, the SQL Server DSN fails to connect to the database with the message that it "Timed out trying to establish a connection."

**The only way we have found to resolve this issue is to delete the DSN and recreate it.**

The operating system is Windows Server 2016 and the Java JVM is Java SE 11.0.12.  Our instance of ColdFusion is up-to-date with current patches.  The database is SQL Server 2019.  We are using a trusted connection to the database (i.e., the ColdFusion AD service account has a login entry in the database).

I can also duplicate this issue on our development server running ColdFusion 2016.

We have various other DSNs that connect to an Oracle 19c database and none of these DSNs experience connectivity issues after service restart or server reboot.  It is only the SQL Server.  We have also confirmed the TCP/IP protocols for SQL Server are enabled.

In development, I tried the MS SQL Server JDBC driver.  It worked well with mixed mode, but I ran into configuration/permissions issues with the mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll to enable integrated security.  Additionally, using this library is not supported by Adobe.

Any assistance anyone can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably be best contacting their CF installation support: cf.install@adobe.com. Fallback would be the CFML Slack where lots of the adobe CF dev team hangs out.. Join here. https://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/. Everything seems to fit the support matrix for that version of CF, Java and SQL Server. Exactly what was the last update for any of these pieces when this connectivity issue started? If you revert that update, does the connection work?

Comment: I really want to thank you for the information about the CF installation support and the CFML slack channel.  When this issue seemed to really start cropping up is around the May - June timeframe which is a few months later than the last patch, so it is a possibility that patch may have screwed something up.  I'm reticent about rolling back because this is a production machine.  This is a government machine and we get scanned continuously to ensure that our site has the latest patches, etc., etc.  I will keep researching and looking into it.  Thanks again!